# how to use classnames library for React.js

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to reacj.js and I'm trying to use the library classnames (https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) which supposedly is like Angular's ng-class. I checked their documentation but I'm not really understanding how it works. 
Has anyone used it? could you show me an example?

Comment: The examples are provided on the very page you provided a link to. We can copy it once again, not sure if that is what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's one example for you, you can try changing green to false.

```
var Comp1 = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var g = classNames({green: true});
    return(
      <div className={g}>hello world</div>
    );
  }
});

var Main = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return(
      <div>
        <Comp1 />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

React.render(<Main />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

jsbin: http://jsbin.com/yipiyizano/edit?js,console,output

Answer (score 0):

..and if you want to add/remove classes with some conditions, you can use:

```
class Main extends React.Component {
 constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isChecked: false
    }
  }
  const g = classNames({
    green: true,
    'border-red': !this.state.isChecked
  })
  handleClick = () => {
  this.setState({
    isChecked: !this.state.isChecked
  })
  }
  render() {
    return ( 
      <button className = {classNames} onClick = {handleClick} />
    )
  }
}
export default Main;
```