# Why and how to use classnames utility in React components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

Could you please explain to me in a simple way what is the purpose of using [Classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) utility in React code? I've just read Classnames docs, but I still can't grasp what is the main reason to use it in code like so:

```
import classnames from 'classnames';
[...]
render() {
  const { className } = this.props

  return (
    <div className={classnames('search', className)}>
      <div className="search-bar-wrapper">
        <form className="search-form" onSubmit={this.onSearch.bind(this)}>
          <div className="search-bar">
            <label className="screen-reader-only" htmlFor="header-search-form">Search</label> [...]
```

Full version of this code (jsx):
https://jsfiddle.net/John_Taylor/j8d42m2f/2/

I don't understand what is going on this line of code:

```
<div className={classnames('search', className)}>
```

I've also read that (
[how to use classnames library for React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32343167/how-to-use-classnames-library-for-react-js) ) answer, but I still have problems with understanding **my code** snippet.

Answer (score 9):

`classnames` library lets you join different `classes` based on different conditions in a simpler way.

Suppose you have 2 classes of which one is going to get used every time but the second one gets used based on some condition. So without `classnames` library you would something like this

```
render() {
  const classnames = 'firstClass';

  if (someCondition) {
    classnames += ' secondClass'
  }

  return(
   <input className={classnames} .. />
  );
}
```

But with `classnames` library you would do that in this way

```
render() {
  const classnames = {'firstClass', {'secondClass': someCondition}}
  return(
   <input className={classnames} .. />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, `<div className={classnames('search', className)}>`is equivalent to `` <div className={`search ${className}`}> ``.

`classnames`is mainly useful when you have to deal with conditional classes.

Answer (score 1):

Classnames make it easy to apply class names to react component conditionally.

For example: Let create a state and apply a class to the button component when the button is clicked

```
const [isActive, setActive] = setState(false);
   import classnames from "classnames"
   var buttonClasses = classnames({
               "btn": true,
                "btn__active": isActive;
              )}
<button className={buttonClasses} onClick={() => setActive(!isActive)}>Make me active</button>
```

This code will apply the "isActive" class to the button when it is clicked.
I hope this help answer your question

Answer (score 0):

If used the way you use it in your script *classnames* simply joins the strings you give it with spaces.

```
const className = 'x';
const result = classnames('search', className);
// result == 'search x'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should attempt reading the docs one more time, they are very clear. Specifically, this part:

So where you may have the following code to generate a className prop for a  in React:

```
var Button = React.createClass({
  // ...
  render () {
    var btnClass = 'btn';
    if (this.state.isPressed) btnClass += ' btn-pressed';
    else if (this.state.isHovered) btnClass += ' btn-over';
    return <button className={btnClass}>{this.props.label}</button>;
  }
});
```

You can express the conditional classes more simply as an object:

```
var classNames = require('classnames');

var Button = React.createClass({
  // ...
  render () {
    var btnClass = classNames({
      btn: true,
      'btn-pressed': this.state.isPressed,
      'btn-over': !this.state.isPressed && this.state.isHovered
    });
    return <button className={btnClass}>{this.props.label}</button>;
  }
});
```

The sole purpose of the library here is to remove the need of writing ugly code to dynamically add classes to something, and just use a consistent syntax instead.

Another example:

```
var Button = React.createClass({
  render () {
    return <button className={this.props.foo ? 'bar' : 'baz' + this.props.bar ? 'baz' : 'foo'}>{this.props.label}</button>;
  }
});
```

That is really hard to read. There is a lot of code out there that looks similar to that.

Here is a better way, using classnames:

```
var classes = classNames({
    bar: this.props.foo,
    baz: !this.props.foo,
    active: this.props.bar,
    hover: !this.props.bar
});

var Button = React.createClass({
  render () {
    return <button className={classes}>{this.props.label}</button>;
  }
});
```

It's very clear there what's happening. If the values in the object are true, the key will be appended to the class. So in that example, the final class will be `bar active`, given `this.props.foo` is truthy and `this.props.bar` is truthy.

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet

```
<div className={classnames('search', className)}>
```

is equivalent to:

```
<div className={`search ${className ? className : ""}`}>
```

so in this particular case it's just encapsulates ternary operator from inside template string. Which is small but improvement - harder to produce bug in.

Probably it is  simplest case of using `classnames`, however when you'll have more  and more conditions around your class name manipulations, it is going to be more and more useful