# How to change background color of a toast depending on theme? react-toastify

Tags: css, reactjs, react-toastify

I got react-toastify installed, and my toasts are working, but I want to add them some custom styling depending on a theme, and none of the solutions I saw are working in my case.

I don't want to overcomplicate it, I just want to change background color, maybe borders, font color, etc.

[image]

I tried class overriding which documentation is saying about - it's not working.

```css
.Toastify__toast-theme--colored.Toastify__toast--error {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}
```

I tried my own `className` and pass it to certein toast - it's not working.

```js
toast.error('here some error', {
          className: 'toast-error'
        });
```

```css
.toast-error {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}
```

And these themed classes are not even added to the `toast.success()` or `toast.error()`

I tried to override values in the core css file that im importing, and it's not working.
And if I set `background-color: red` to the actual class that is added, then I get red background on `toast.success()` as well.

Here is [documentation](https://fkhadra.github.io/react-toastify/how-to-style).
[image]

How to deal with this?

Comment: Please don't add images ,paste text or code instead.

Answer (score 0):

using classnames should be the solution to your problem

```
className={classnames("Toastify__toast-theme--colored", {
          "toast-error": // here the condition by which toast-error class should pop up
        })}
```

Comment: Can you provide some more details about this answer? Like full ```toast.error()``` call with options of customs styles or calsses?

Comment: you need to return a boolean as a condition for the class to be used or not. for example if `className={classnames("Toastify__toast-theme--colored", {"toast-error": true})}` on the DOM you will see both  `Toastify__toast-theme--colored` and  `toast-error` classes. otherwise only  `Toastify__toast-theme--colored`

Comment: Where am I supposed to specify that? Can you link some docs for that solution? When I simply copy and paste your code, Im getting errors and app is crashing.

Comment: probably because you don't have the package installed in your app. here the [documentation](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames)

Comment: How is this solving problem with styling in react-toastify? Is this an addiotional package from react-toastify for that purpose?

Comment: no, it's an utility useful for conditional rendering of classes here an answer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46792826/why-and-how-to-use-classnames-utility-in-react-components with different examples